# Unwanted whitespace below android webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, bottom-sheet

I am trying to load webview inside a bottomsheet. The webview is tabbed with uneven content.So whenever I switch from smaller content tab to larger content tab and then go back to previous tab I see lots of white space.
Can any one tell me whats the issue. Can we solve it from native?

Here is my xml:

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nested_scrol"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
    
                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/proteksi_webview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Solution: don't put webview in a NestedScrollView. don't use webview in wrap_contents mode, check it out here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37077954#c10

Comment: if i don't put webview in nestedscrollview then i can't scroll webview @UuuUuu

Comment: you can try some solutions in above link